# How do I open max files from within code?

Tags: c++, sdk, 3dsmax

I have a seemingly very elementary question. I want to open a .max file from my c++ plugin code without an open file dialog.

No matter what I do this code crashes 3ds Max:

```
ip->LoadFromFile((_T("C:\\thescene.max"), TRUE);
```

No error message details. Max just crashes whenever I invoke this code. I can open the file manually.

Is there any obvious mistake anyone can see? I am using Max 2014 and everything else is working OK.

Comment: What is `ip`? Is it a valid pointer?

Comment: It is a valid pointer to the interface class declared as: Interface *ip;

Comment: @DanielAdmassu That's an uninitialised pointer; it's not valid.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I assure you that it is initialized and valid. In a max sdk plugin you do everything related to the scene through this interface. I use it for everything else in my code. And it works ok. Just this member function crashes it.

Comment: @DanielAdmassu Do as advised and post a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please. There's nothing wrong with what you poated appearantly.

Comment: Question do not provide enough context even to have a clue what is a problem, so there is no chance to receive any answer. You can choose: adjust to rules of SO (read links provided) or wait for answer for eternity (or until question is closed).

Comment: The thing is that there's really no more adjacent code that I can post here. The mentioned code resides alone in its function like this: void open_file () {ip-> LoadFromFile (_T ("c:\thescene.max"));} The interface pointer works well for everything else in other parts of my plugin, for example to create nodes and geometry. I implemented the code exactly as mentioned in the documentation. I was hoping for someone who encountered the same problem or if there was a known issue with it.